# How to use int i for selecting text box NR

Tags: c#, string, winforms, names

I have 10 text boxes. Like `textBox1.Text` , `textBox2.Text` and so on. I need to use `textBox2.Text if i=2`, `textBox2.Text if i =3` and so on.
I did:

```
string t = "textBox"+i+".Text";
```

But outcome coming as "textBox1.Text".
How to insert 'i' Value into textBox name instead of 1. And get the outcome as textBox1.Text 
So I can use it as name and pass value from textbox to my program.

Comment: Is this a web application (WebForms, MVC, etc) or a desktop application (WinForms, WPF, etc). Both have "TextBox" controls, but the answer's very different based on which world you're developing in.

Comment: *I need to use textBox2.Text if i=2. textBox2.Text if i =3 and so on.* Huh?

Comment: its winForm app

Answer (score 3):

Based on what I think you are asking, you could store a reference to each `TextBox` in an array and then use your `int` to reference it.

```
TextBox[] boxes = new TextBox[10];
boxes[0] = textBox1;
// ... follow the pattern
boxes[9] = textBox10;

string value = boxes[i-1].Text; // Gets the value of the textBoxi.Text
```

Comment: I can't put textBox1.Text to an array. I'm getting a message as: Cannot implicit convert type 'string' to 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'

Comment: @RaimondasLukosius - look at the code sample I wrote. You don't put `textBox1.Text` in the array, you just put `textBox1` in the array.  Then when you need the text you get it by calling `boxes[i-1].Text`

Comment: Your method is easy and working well I just realized one of the boxes was combo box named as textBox1. When I replaced this one all went well.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like so:

```
private TextBox GetTB(int i) {
    string name = "textBox" + i.ToString();
    foreach (var ctrl in Controls) {
         var tbox = ctrl as TextBox;
         if (tbox?.Name == name) return tbox;
    }
    return null
}
```

Comment: Its not just textBox +i       its     textBox +1+.Text

Comment: The method just gets the text box you need. So you use it like `var tb = GetTB(2)?.Text;`

Comment: I need to insert i in between   textBox  and .Text

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, if you need to access them in C# code this way, would be to maintain an array or `List` of these textboxes, indexed in order of their numeric value. Then you could simply reference `textBoxes[i-1]` and get the textbox numbered "i". How you get that array depends on exactly what you're developing. For WinForms, you can use a little Linq on the Form.Controls property:

```
    public static IEnumerable<Control> Flatten(this IEnumerable<Control> controls)        
    {
        var results = new List<Control>();

        foreach (var control in controls)
        {
            results.Add(control);
            control.Controls.OfType<Control>().Flatten(results);
        }

        return results;
    }

    private static void Flatten(this IEnumerable<Control> controls, List<Control> results)
    {
        foreach (var control in controls)
        {
            results.Add(control);
            control.Controls.OfType<Control>().Flatten(results);
        }
    }

    ...

    var textboxes = Form.Controls.Flatten()
                    .OfType<TextBox>()
                    .Where(t=>t.Name.StartsWith("textBox"))
                    .OrderBy(t=>t.Name)
                    .ToArray();
```